# monacaで変数が使えない場合

Tags: javascript, monaca, jquery

日時の計算をしようとしています。 
codepenでは問題なくログに結果が表示されますが
monacaで試すとnullになってしまいます
変数ではなくnew Date()に日時を直接指定してもだめでした。
原因がわかりませんのでよろしくお願い致します。

```
var gg = '2015-12-31 23:59';　　　　
var ff = '2015-12-31 23:56';

　　　　　　
var a = new Date(gg);　　　　　　　
var b = new Date(ff);　　　　　　　　　　　
var dd = a - b;　　　　
console.log(dd);
```

Answer (score 1):

### console.logについて

実行環境の情報（IDEのプレビューか、iOS/Androidデバッガーか）が無いので確定的なことは言えないですが、iOS版のMonacaデバッガーではconsole.logは使えなかった記憶があります。

提示されているソースを実行してみたところ、私の手元の環境（Windows 8.1, Chrome 43, iOS 8.3, ストア版Monacaデバッガー4.0.1）では、そもそもnullさえ出力されない状態でした。

公式のドキュメントによると、

> iOS アプリに関しては、Mac の Safari のリモートデバッグ機能と Monaca デバッガーを連携させて、デバッグを行えます。これにより、以下の機能が使用できます。
>   Console を使用したデバッグ : Console 上で、メッセージの出力とデバッグセッションを行います。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/manual/debugger/debug/#by-debugger-usb

と書いてあります。逆に言えば、Mac+Safariのリモートデバッグ機能を使わない場合には、consoleは使えないという風に読めます。私の手元では、iOSのMonacaデバッガーでは何も出力されませんでしたが、IDEのプレビューではconsole.logが出力されることを確認できました。

### 日付文字列について

提示されているJavaScriptコードにはバグを生みかねない問題があります。
Dateオブジェクトに渡している日付形式の文字列が、標準で定められた形式に即していないため、ブラウザの実装次第では正しく解釈されません。
（提示されたソースコードを実行したところ、Chrome 43では180000と出ましたが、Firefox 38ではNaNになりました）

iOS/AndroidのWebViewで、'2015-12-31 23:59'という形式がどう解釈されるかは把握していないですが、安全性を考えると、何かしらの標準に則った形式にすべきです（以下はISO8601の例です）。

```
var gg = '2015-12-31T23:59:00+0900';
var ff = '2015-12-31T23:56:00+0900';
var a = new Date(gg);
var b = new Date(ff);
var dd = a - b;
console.log(dd);
```

日付文字列の形式については以下のページなどを参考にしてください。
http://so-zou.jp/web-app/tech/programming/javascript/grammar/object/date.htm

Answer (score 1):

iOSデバッガー(4.0.1)、iOS8.3上
及び
Androidデバッガー(4.0.2)、Android5.1.1上
で検証しました。

デバイス上でもconsole.logの内容はきちんと出ますので、ご安心を。

本題ですが、なぜconsole.log(dd);がnullになるのかというと、ggとffがきちんと日付文字列として認識されず、aとbがdateオブジェクト生成に失敗するからです。

では、ggやffにどう書けばいいかですが、

```
var gg = '2015/12/31 23:59';
var ff = '2015-12-31T23:56:00.000+09:00';
```

などとして下さい。
つまり、年月日の区切りを「-」ではなく「/」にするか、
書式に従うなら「yyyy-mm-ddTtt:mm:ss.sss+mm:ss」（+09:00の部分は日本標準時の場合）として下さい。

```
var gg = '2015/12/31 23:59';
var ff = '2015-12-31T23:56:00.000+09:00';
var a = new Date(gg);
var b = new Date(ff);
console.debug("a-localestr"+a.toLocaleString());
console.log("b-localestr"+b.toLocaleString());
console.debug("a-gettime"+a.getTime());
console.log("b-gettime"+b.getTime());
var dd = a - b ; 
var ee = a.getTime() - b.getTime();
console.log("dd"+dd);
console.log("ee"+ee);
```